# Edit last tr of table's sub element

Tags: html, css

I have a table where the `<ul>` is expanding off the page on my last `<td>`, I'm trying to move that `<td>` up by targetting the last td of my table.

I am trying to get the last td's ul and edit the css for that specific element. I have tried to add the following with no luck.

```css
  table td:last-child: .dropdown-menu {
  {
    margin: -121px 0 0 0 !important;
  }
```

```html
<table class="my-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>hello</td>
      <td>hello</td>
      <td>
        <span class="dropdown">
         <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-xs" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Actions <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" style="min-width: 100px">
          <li><a style="text-decoration: none !important; cursor: pointer;" class="benefitRecipientDelete">Delete</a></li>
          </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>hello</td>
      <td>hello</td>
      <td>
        <span class="dropdown">
         <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-xs" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Actions <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" style="min-width: 100px">
          <li><a style="text-decoration: none !important; cursor: pointer;" class="benefitRecipientDelete">Delete</a></li>
          </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>hello</td>
      <td>hello</td>
      <td>
        <span class="dropdown">
         <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-xs" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Actions <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" style="min-width: 100px">
          <li><a style="text-decoration: none !important; cursor: pointer;" class="benefitRecipientDelete">Delete</a></li>
          </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I  edit the drop-downmenu/ul of the last td in my table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a colon behind the pseudo code and double opening curly braces.

```css
table td:last-child .dropdown-menu {
  margin: -121px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<table class="my-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>hello</td>
      <td>hello</td>
      <td>
        <span class="dropdown">
         <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-xs" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Actions <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" style="min-width: 100px">
          <li><a style="text-decoration: none !important; cursor: pointer;" class="benefitRecipientDelete">Delete</a></li>
        </ul>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>hello</td>
      <td>hello</td>
      <td>
        <span class="dropdown">
         <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-xs" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Actions <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" style="min-width: 100px">
          <li><a style="text-decoration: none !important; cursor: pointer;" class="benefitRecipientDelete">Delete</a></li>
        </ul>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>hello</td>
      <td>hello</td>
      <td>
        <span class="dropdown">
         <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-xs" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Actions <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" style="min-width: 100px">
          <li><a style="text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer;" class="benefitRecipientDelete">Delete</a></li>
        </ul>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```